# Neutral element for min() and max() in OpenCL reduction

Tags: floating-point, opencl

I'm doing a reduction (finding the minimum and maximum) of a `float[]` array on a GPU through OpenCL.

I'm loading the some elements from `global` memory into `local` memory for each workgroup. When the global size isn't a multiple of the workgroup size, I pad the global size, such that it becomes a multiple of the global size. Work-items past the end of the array put the neutral element of the reduction into `local` memory.

But what should that neutral element be for `max()` -- the maximum function?
[The OpenCL documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/mathConstants.html) gives `MAXFLOAT`, `HUGE_VALF` and `INFINITY` as very large positive (or unsigned) `float` values. 
Does it makes sense to have the neutral element to be `-INFINITY` for example?

Right now I'm using `HUGE_VALF` as the neutral element for `min()`, but the docs also say that `HUGE_VALF` is used as an error value, so maybe that's a bad idea.

Reduction kernel (Code):

```c
#define NEUTRAL_ELEMENT HUGE_VALF
#define REDUCTION_OP min

__kernel void reduce(__global float* weights,
                     __local float* weights_cached
                    )
{
  unsigned int id = get_global_id(0);

  // Load data
  if (id < {{ point_count }}) {
    weights_cached[get_local_id(0)] = weights[id];
  } else {
    weights_cached[get_local_id(0)] = NEUTRAL_ELEMENT;
  }

  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

  // Reduce
  for(unsigned int stride = get_local_size(0) / 2; stride >= 1; stride /= 2) {
    if (get_local_id(0) < stride) {
      weights_cached[get_local_id(0)] = REDUCTION_OP(weights_cached[get_local_id(0)], weights_cached[get_local_id(0) + stride]);
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
  }

  // Save
  weights[get_group_id(0)] = weights_cached[0];
}
```

**Edit:**
I actually ended up using `fmin()` and `fmax()` together with `NAN` as the neutral element -- this is basically guaranteed to work according to the [OpenCL documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/fmax.html) as the numerical value will always be returned (`NAN` is only returned if two `NAN` values are given).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the OpenCL standard:

> HUGE_VALF evaluates to +infinity.

So there's no real difference (except for implied intent) between using `HUGE_VALF` and `INFINITY`; either will work correctly for a `min` reduction.  In terms of clarity, I have a slight preference for `INFINITY`, as `HUGE_VALF` is conceptually intended for edge-case returns, which this isn't.

Similarly, use `-INFINITY` for a `max` reduction.

`MAX_FLOAT` will not behave correctly as a neutral element if your array contains infinities.

Comment: Since the question displays some uncertainty abut -INFINITY, we might want to emphasize that this is a regular supported thing. You can apply the unary `-` operator to INFINITY and get the value that is -infinity, and it should work as expected from its mathematical meaning.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: right; the existence of -infinity is guaranteed by the OpenCL standard (specifically by the requirement that `float` be the IEEE-754 binary32 format).